# разделение ширины окна для 2 div, разных по ширине

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо вертикальное меню слева контейнера, а справа от него контент(картинка).
Как разделить ширину окна в пропорциях примерно 25/75.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрели уже [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) и/или [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)?

Comment: пытался, не нашел нужного

Comment: Приложите к вопросу свои попытки, пожалуйста. Нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M, вставьте там ваш код по нужным секциям, обязательно нажмите кнопку "Привести в порядок", после нажмите на "Запустить". Убедитесь, что всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких других ошибок, кроме тех, о которых вы спрашиваете. Только после всего этого в конце нажмите на "Вставить в сообщение"

Comment: мужик. ты просто выставляешь в % им ширину и высоту. И все. вставь сюда свой код и тебе его отредактируют

Answer (score -1):

На "grid" удобней и меньше писать, но если вдруг ".aside" должен менять ширину, схлопываться например, тогда на "flex" лучше делать, так как манипуляции уже будут идти именно с шириной ".aside".

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
}
.flex-wrapper .aside {
  min-width: 100px;
  
}
.flex-wrapper .content {
  width: 100%;
}
.aside {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  column-gap: 30px; 
}
```

```html
<h1>На флексах</h1>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="aside"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<h1>На Гридах</h1>
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="aside"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Во первых у вас нет разделения на 25% и 75%, чтобы убедиться достаточно открыть ваш ответ на весь экран. Во вторых, пустота между блоками не требовалась вообще, непонятно почему вы это добавили. А ещё было бы не плохо добавить решение без `flexbox` и `grid`, а на обычных `block`, но это уже на ваше усмотрение